# mount:mounting /dev/sda1 on /boot/efi failed: No such device

Tags: linux

I booted the Linux system through Grub, but the result is stuck in **mount:mounting /dev/sda1 on /boot/efi failed: No such device**. The detailed screenshot below seems to indicate that there is a problem with my root file system, but I am not sure where the problem is. Why is there no problem with `sda2` and `sda3`, but there is a problem with `sda1`?

By the way, my keyboard is also unavailable at the moment.

Screenshot of the problem

[image]

Screenshot of fstab in grub shell:

[image]

Screenshot of `sudo /sbin/parted /dev/sda print` in linux live:
[image]

reply **telcoM**:
Screenshot of add an empty `/run` directory:

[image]

Comment: Did you confirm UUID matches. `lsblk -e 7 -o name,fstype,size,fsused,label,partlabel,mountpoint,uuid,partuuid` Have you tried dosfsck on the ESP. `sudo fsck.vfat -t -a /dev/sdXY` # where X is drive and Y is partition. Also `man dosfsck`

Comment: I see at the top of the first image mdadm messages. You have some sort of RAID configuration?

Comment: @oldfred Yes, I have compared and the uuid matches.    I didn't use `sudo fsck.vfat -t -a /dev/sdXY`, I just used `sudo/sbin/mkfs.fat - F32 /dev/sda1` after the parted partition.

Comment: @schrodingerscatcuriosity Sorry, I'm not sure where this configuration is?

Comment: @oldfred After executing `sudo/sbin/mkfs.fat - F32 /dev/sda1`, there is still a problem with executing `sudo fsck.vfat -t -a /dev/sda1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a packaged Debian standard kernel, or your customized one?

If a customized kernel, do you have the driver for the `vfat` filesystem type available?

Since the root filesystem (`/dev/sda3`) and the `/boot` filesystem (`/dev/sda2`) are getting successfully mounted, you now have drivers for your disk controller, disk, partitioning scheme and `ext4` filesystems successfully loaded. But the `/dev/sda1` (the EFI System Partition, to be mounted to `/boot/efi`) uses a different filesystem type.

I also note the message `mount: mounting /run at /root/run failed: No such file or directory`. At that point, the initramfs script is trying to mount the `/run` tmpfs filesystem to `/root/run` i.e. what will be the real `/run` once the script switches away from initramfs to the real root filesystem. Maybe your root filesystem does not include an empty `/run` directory that would act as a mount point for the RAM-based tmpfs filesystem?

Comment: I am using a customized kernel，the driver for the `vfat` filesystem type available?Sorry, I am a beginner and I am not very sure where to find and place this driver. I just compiled busybox and generated the root file system.    Indeed, there is no empty `/run` folder, I will add it.

Comment: after added an empty `/run`，The `mount: mounting /run at /root/run failed: No such file or directory` problem has been resolved.

Comment: I looked at the`.config` file in the kernel src directory, and the option `CONFIG_VFAT_FS` is `m`, which means that the kernel supports `vfat`.